# GDAL ECW & MrSID Extensions for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I've added the GDAL extensions to GeoServer and it worked. However, I followed the instructions in order to add GDAL ECW & MrSID Extensions for GeoServer documented in the installation guide (Adding support for ECW and MrSID on Windows) but I got the error in the screenshot below:

[image]

Considering that I've created a `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` variable in the environments variables as shown below

[image]

And not appearing in the GeoServer. I am using GeoServer 2.8.1

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Is GeoServer running as a service using the standard installer?

In any case the error looks like a low level error, GDAL related. I suggest to look around for solutions regardless of GeoServer.

Comment: I start and stop Geoserver Manually using start/stop Geoserver commands (Its not a service).
may you please elaborate more about the possible solutions?

Comment: The error does not seem to be related to GeoServer but rather a problem with the GDAL dlls tehmselves. 

I would look around specifically for that problem on Windows.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, but when I run "gdalinfo --format MrSID" it seems happy. If the extension couldn't be loaded I'd expect to get an error, but perhaps not? I downloaded GDAL and the plugin dlls off the geoserver website.

Answer (score 4):

After experiencing exactly the same problem, the only way that I could get it to work was to install 32bit Java 8 then 32bit GDAL along with the 32bit MrSID and ECW extensions.